# MVC5: Digital Signage website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make a digital signage website which will run on the TV screens of my company.  My thought was to use MVC to make it fairly easy to split the presentation layer and the data layer.  I need a site that shows a variety of pages - some will have Google-style dashboard controls like Gauges and tables, some announcements, and a news ticker crawling along the bottom while the pages flip in and out.  The problem is that I am not too familiar with MVC.

I have been having lots of problems getting a website that will switch to a new page every 5 or 10 seconds.  I am confused with how to use layout pages, partial views, and calling back into the controller.  I have been working on this for four days so I have tons of code, but I don't want to paste it all in here.

Just the basics of what I have tried (I will leave out boilerplate stuff like the head element and stuff where I am not doing anything special):

**_ViewStart**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**_Layout**

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()        
</div>

<footer>
    <hr />
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"><img src="http://www.html.am/images/html-codes/marquees/fish-swimming.gif" width="94" height="88" alt="Swimming fish" /></marquee>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
</footer>
```

**Company1_Layout**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<body class="greybackground container">
<header>
    <img src="~/images/homesafetymatters_header.png" alt="Home Safety Matters"/>
</header>
<div class="container body-content" style="height:100%">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

**Home**
(This is where I am trying to start the site, and then start calling new pages to appear)

```
@model DigitalSignsPages.Models.Home

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to Digital Signage v2.0</h2>


    <script>
    window.setInterval(yourfunction, 5000);

    function yourfunction() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Gauge/GoToHSMGauge',
            data: { id: 1 },
            success: function () {
                console.log('Added');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**GaugeController**

```
public ActionResult GoToBrooksGauge(int id)
    {
        decimal answer = repository.GetGaugeData("001", 1);
        ViewBag.Title = "Gauge";
        ViewBag.Pct = answer;
        return View("HSMGauge");
    }
```

**Problems I have been having**
I was trying to call an action directly in my javascript function, and that sort of worked, but it seemed to flush out any HTML after that call directly to the page so there would be a couple end brackets and semi-colons and such.  I think I have to use AJAX to call the controller action method, and indeed, the breakpoint in my controller gets hit every 5 seconds, but nothing happens.  No no View appears.

I think I have to specify an area for the new View to appear, like a , and then I call $("#foo")......what?  load, or html?  I am not sure, neither seems to do anything.  But it seems like I should use a Render action, but I am not sure if I should use RenderPartial()...doesn't that make it part of the Home.cshtml page?  I want a new page to appear, HSMGauge.cshtml.

Also, I tried putting the timer in the _Layout page, and then to keep a javascript variable that could be passed to a controller, but there seems to be a problem with that because I would get an error that the variable was out of scope when I do that.  So now my idea was to have the Home.cshtml kick off the site, and then as the action method in each controller gets called it returns a certain view to be opened.  But as I said, nothing happens when the action in the controller gets called.  No errors, just nothing.

Basically, if someone has the time or energy, could they point out some of the things I am doing wrong, some good examples or sites that teach me how to do this that I have not been able to find with Google, or maybe just tell me that I am barking up the wrong tree with MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description I'd make a [Single Page Application (SPA)](http://www.johnpapa.net/pageinspa/) using a client side Javascript framework something like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) against a [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) backend. If you are changing pages often and using dashboards it will give a far nicer flicker free effect. You can use transitions between pages (like powerpoint) and also dashboard components can easily be loaded asynchronously so pages load quicker. Data can be cached client side using tools like Breeze

For learning AngularJS - I'd recommend looking at [John Pappas](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/) code camp PluarlSight training course. I learned it in a matter of days. He has a great getting started template/framework called H[otTowel.Angular.Breeze](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HotTowel.Angular.Breeze/) on nuget

In my opinion the future of web applications is largely client side Apps calling an API. More and more applications go that way. AngularJS is popular with great integration with other frameworks etc. MS is investing in .Net WebAPI and MVC6 in vNext so I think it is a good stack

Comment: Thank you, this is good advice.  I was making things too complicated I guess.  It was suggested that I use MVC but that might not be the best framework for what I am trying to do.  I like what I see of Angular so far.

Comment: You can certainly combine both MVC and Angular we do. However I'd have thought just WebAPI probably makes life simpler. After that you will also have a well defined API which could be used by mobile applications, customers or anything else in the future